# run nfs server version 3 only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, nfs

I'm a RHEL guy, and new to debian/ubuntu, I have just setup an nfs server, and when I mount a share on a client, it uses version 4, how can I get the server to run with nfs version 3 only?

PS: our company usues JAVA application and it only works with NFS V3, if we use V4, the application starts acting up.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the version with the [`nfsvers` mount option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/nfs.5.html#contenttoc3):

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 nfs:/home /home
```